# Withdraw functions implementation

Tags: solidity, contract-design, ether

I'm writing a smart contract where subscribers make a bid, post doing so owner selects one and sends him data as well as ends the contract. If data is valid, winner releases the funds so owner can withdraw them.

My issue here is I'd like upon contract closure, that only other subscribers not the winner to be able to withdraw their funds however, not the winner as well as the owner.

Post release the owner can claim his funds.

Any ideas how to do so.

```
function done() onlyOwner public{
    require (state == State.Active, "Contract still working.");
    state = State.WinnerSelected;
}

function withdraw() external onlyOwner payable{
    require (state == State.WinnerSelected, "Contract not closed to withdraw.");
    owner.transfer((address(this).balance));
}

function release() public {
    require(payments[msg.sender] > 0, 'Sender has not paid into escrow.');
    require(released[msg.sender] == 0, 'Sender has already released funds.');
    released[msg.sender] = payments[msg.sender];
    //state = State.WinnerSelected;
}

function makeBid(string memory _extraData) public inState(State.Active) payable returns(uint bidIterator) {
    require(msg.value > 0, "No value inserted");
    require(bidders <= 3, "Contract reached max registrations");
    require(payments[msg.sender] == 0, 'Sender previously paid into escrow.');
    bids.push(Bid(msg.sender, msg.value, _extraData, true));
    payments[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    bidders ++; 
    //if (bidders < 4){
    // state = State.closed;
    //}
    return bids.length - 1;
}
```

Comment: 1. The description at the top of the question is extremely unclear IMO.

Comment: 2. The message `"Contract still working."` should in fact be `"Contract no longer working."`.

Comment: 3. The message `"Contract not closed to withdraw."` is confusing IMO. It should probably be `"Contract not yet opened for withdrawals."` or something similar.

Comment: 4. In `owner.transfer((address(this).balance));` you'll be transferring all o the funds in the contract to `owner`. I'm pretty ure that this is not your actual intention (and I'm petty sure that I've already mentioned that in a comment to an earlier question of yours).

Comment: 5. At the end of function `release()`, I believe that you should do `payments[msg.sender] = 0;`., though I cannot be sure, because you don't seem to do anything with the variable `released`.

Comment: @goodvibration; Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Regarding the owner.transfer yes I want to transfer all the funds left in the contract to the owner, this will be done post ensure that all the not winner bids have withdrew their bids. Thus post doing so the left funds will be that of the winner, thus owner can claim them as his reward.

Comment: The whole withdraw function has been removed, and changed with another for bidders to withdraw then change contract state. Then another claim function post withdraw is done.